# An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll : Cannot find column 3

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have try this code to import data to SQL table but it is showing up the error:
This error occurs when I upload an Excel file, but when I upload Notepad file the information  imported to SQL table.

the place of error:

```
dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
```

So Please can anyone try to figure out the error and can send me the correct code

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
  string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);

  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("PersonId", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(string))});
        
  string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
  foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
  {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
      {
          dt.Rows.Add();
          int i = 0;
          foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
          {
              dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
              i++;
           }
      }
   }

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Server Name;Initial Catalog=AD;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name.
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Employee";
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code assumes that each cell has no more than three values after being split. There is a row where this assumption does not hold.

Comment: What does the string csvData hold? Please add this information to your data so we can help you better.

Comment: _This error occurs when I upload an Excel file, but when I upload Notepad file the information imported to SQL table._ So, is the file from Excel actually a CSV file? Or are you uploading an .xlsx file (which is not CSV format)?

Comment: I wasn't know the difference between  csv And xlsx  file. I was upload an xlsx file but now after uploading csv file the code  working fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: A CSV file is a text file that uses commas (or occasionally some other symbol) as a separator between data elements. An XLSX file is a binary format that can contain far richer detail on tabular data, it's one of the [Office Open XML formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML).